# Does it matter if Height goes before Width? (HTML)

Tags: html

Does it matter whether I specify height or width first in an image html tag?  Is either of these invalid?

```
<img height="400" width="200" src="/picture1.jpg"/>
```

or

```
<img width="200" height="400" src="/picture1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Looks like it, I was looking img specific hence why i missed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will both yield the same output. The way that you code them is a matter of personal preference/organization.

Comment: Thought so, must be another issue why the SEO site I was using is reporting images are being stretched then.  Thx for confirming what I thought.